# Does publishing a message on the same ConsumeContext that received it have any benefits?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm asking about a situation where the consumer gets the message, processes it and then the result of that processing is another message, so something like:

```
class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyMessage> {
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context) {
        // ...do the processing and then:
        await context.Publish<MyResponse>(new()
        {
            Data = "some data"
        });
    }
}
```

So the question is - does using `context.Publish` have any benefits over injecting `IPublishEndpoint`? It would be done if the processing would require another component to be separated from the consumer - another class. Then the result of that component processing would be a message which could be published by the injected `IPublishEndpoint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a consumer (and any of the consumers dependencies), messages published and/or sent should use:

- `ConsumeContext` - easiest in the consumer, since it already has it as part of the method signature.
- `ISendEndpointProvider` or `IPublishEndpoint` - should be injected into any dependencies of the consumer that need to produce messages. MassTransit is essentially redirecting these two interfaces to the current `ConsumeContext` behind the scenes.

> This is also [covered in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My initial question actually comes from the documentation. There you write (related to the ConsumeContext): "This ensures that the correlation headers, message headers, and trace information is propagated to the published message." - since you don't mention the autowire up of these information in the point no. 2 - IPublishEndpoint - I had some doubts. Namely, if I use this interface and not ConsumeContext, will headers and trace information be automatically attached to the message as it would happen had I used ConsumeContext?

Comment: Inside a consumer, yes. Since MassTransit is just returning `ConsumeContext` from the container for those two interfaces, it's essentially the same thing just narrowed to the requested interface.

Comment: Ah, so after all, if I use `IPublishEndpoint` in the scope of a consumer (in a service injected into the consumer), it does put headeres etc. onto the new message? That's great :)